# IC2 ore processing automatically remove bypass products

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-industrialcraft

I’m up to automate my ore processing.

But the question I have is how to get rid of the bypass products (stone dust, tiny piles of...) in the ore washing plant.

How can I automatically get them out of the Machine?

I‘m just using IC2 and BuildCraft.

Comment: I don't know the mod, but have you tried hoppers and pipes? :D

Comment: Can you show the interface of the machine? I think IC2 machines base auto-output on the direction that an object is connected... have an experiemt with pipes etc to see what works and what doesnt